# Como dividir um loop com php?

Tags: php, html

sou bem iniciante, mas gostaria de fazer loop em 2 etapas.
Eu estou fazendo uma consulta em uma pasta e exibindo todas imagens dela.

Gostaria de exibir primeiro 3 imagens.
colocar um texto no meio. E após esse texto continuar a exibir as outras imagens da pasta.

```
<div class="row padding-top-80">
                        <?php

$diretorio = $linha01['diretorio'].'/';
$lista_dir = scandir($diretorio);
// print_r($lista_dir);

    // $caminho = rawurldecode($_REQUEST['diretorio']);
        $img = glob($diretorio."*.{webp,jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
        $contador = count($img);

foreach($img as $img){
  
?>
                    
                        <div class="col-md-4 mt-4 mt-md-4" data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom move 40px over 0.5s after 0.3s">
                            <a href="<?php echo $img;?>" data-fancybox="">
                                <div class="gallery-wrap over-hide border-4 img-wrap">
                                    <?php echo '<img src="'.$img.'" />';?>
                                    <div class="gallery-mask">
                                        <div class="gallery-icon">
                                            <i class="uil uil-plus size-22 color-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

<?php }

?>
'
```

Comment: Desse jeito funcionou, mas como fazer pra exibir somente uma vez após as 3 primeiras imagens e não a cada 3 imagens?
Porque dessa forma, ele exibe o mesmo texto a cada 3 imagens

Answer (score 0):

"Gostaria de exibir primeiro 3 imagens. colocar um texto no meio. E após esse texto continuar a exibir as outras imagens da pasta."

Você não precisa de duas etapas, precisa de uma verificação (if), para exibir ou não o texto.

```
$contador = 0;
foreach ($imagens as $img) {
    // divide o contador por 3, caso o resto seja zero, exibe o texto
    if ($contador > 0 && ($contador % 3) === 0) {
        // exibir aqui o texto, a cada 3 imagens
    }

    // exibir as imagens aqui...

    $contador++; // incrementa o contador de imagens exibidas
}
```